# Does PHP MySQL not support IN?

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, I have a rather long query that only fails when I add an IN statement.  The following query works great in MySQL console directly but returns nothing when done in PHP.

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'something', 'somepassword');

$query = "SELECT * 
FROM alt_table f 
INNER JOIN alt_fac_table_c cl ON (f.id = cl.alt_table2_ida) 
INNER JOIN alt_table c ON (cl.alt_table_idb = c.id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN alt_table_contacts_c con ON (f.id = con.alt_table_ida) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts cc ON (con.alt_table_idb = cc.id) 
WHERE c.name = 'myname' 
AND f.state IN ('AL','FL') ORDER BY fname;";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

The problem is not with connecting with the database and its not with the query itself.  Obviously I have renamed a couple things but the query is the same.  In PHP it returns nothing (No errors, no nothing) but in SSH/Console it returns all of the rows I need.

If I remove "AND f.state IN ('AL','FL') ORDER BY fname;";" the query works but gives me every single state.  So the big question is... does PHP have a Problem with the IN statement?

UPDATE FIX
 It ended up being a problem with the post data. I was posting the single quotes for 'AL',FL'. It was apparently encoding them strangely upon post. I assume some sort of security feature. I took the quote out of the post and added it it server side PHp instead and it works.

Comment: MySQL is MySQL no matter what programming language you're using to interact with it.

Comment: Hate to be rude, but doesn't help at all as this exact statement works when querying against the database directly in a shell.

Comment: Perhaps if you posted an unabridged code we might be able to help? Also, check for errors with `mysql_error()`. I also presume that you're actually doing something with the result set and not just relying on it showing you the rows with `echo $result;` or similar? `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { print_r( $row ); }`

Comment: Yes, it does something with it.  I added the error check and I do get an error .  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''AL','FL')"   Which is strange because it works in MySQl

Comment: Possibly caused by an odd newline character or something as a result of copying and pasting from the terminal? I can't see anything wrong syntactically. Perhaps you could just delete the entire `AND f.state` line and type it in manually. Are you able to run the query in PHPMyAdmin or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being a problem with the post data.  I was posting the single quotes for 'AL',FL'.  It was apparently encoding them strangely upon post.  I assume some sort of security feature.  I took the quote out of the post and added it it server side PHp instead and it works.

Answer (score 6):

You've neglected to select a database...

```
mysql_select_db('database_name', $db);
```

This should go just after the call to the `mysql_connect()` function.

http://uk.php.net/mysql_select_db

It will provide a true/false on success so you can use the following to ensure it connects.

```
if( ! mysql_select_db('database_name', $db) ) {
    die('failed to select database');
}
```

In addition to the above, you can modify the following line

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

To be more like the following. This will show you any errors returned, and in your case a `No database selected` error

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: The other post (that has since been deleted) also made a good point - get rid of the semicolon in the query as it doesn't need to be there.

Comment: True, it doesn't need to be there. In this case however, it wont cause any harm as it's at the end of the query.

Comment: Not the issue.  I just neglected to provide that line in my above code snippet.  See my comment where I say it works fine with out the IN statement.

Comment: ... but it doesn't cause any problem as well. And after all the fixes - yes, MySQL does support IN() and it doesn't depend on PHP.

Comment: I can assure you that the `IN` expression works fine with MySQL (and PHP incidentally).  If it didn't, I'd have quite a bit of broken software on my hands.

Comment: Have you added the `or die(mysql_error());` This should give us more information to go on

Comment: @Ben Swinburne That was a good idea.  Now I get an error.  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''AL','FL')"

Answer (score 0):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

`The query string should not end with a semicolon.`

Try removing just that and see if it works.